# Where clause rails -- using two Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Not sure of the best way to do this - I have a where clause that I need to use two models In order to get list results for an autocomplete.  I have a 'Membership' model that contains either a 'User' reference or a 'Member' reference (either the user_id is nil or the member_id is nil, but not both).

I need to list out both the User names AND the Member names for the current_user, plucking the user_id if not nil or the member_id, respectively.

I tried to add an && to the where clause but it doesn't seem to be working

```
 User.where(id:  current_user.memberships.pluck(&:user_id)) && Member.where(id: current_user.memberships.pluck(&:member_id)
```

How can I make this work and make it Railsy?

Comment: Your && means you want to join 2 queries or something else?

Comment: *"It doesn't seem to be working"* is not really helpful. What does not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes. I need to list out names for both members and users depending on if the user_id or if the member_id has a reference in the Membership record - I need to list them as one collection.

Comment: what is the relations here, could you explain more:  eg: User has many memberships, Membership belongs to a member, MemberShip belongs to a user?

Comment: @mike0416 can you try my answer and let me know if that works for you? If not, let me know what you want. I will try to update my answer.

Comment: @K M Rakibul Islam - I wrote this on my phone. I'll be home I a bit. This seems reasonable. I didn't think to break it up into two variables and concat the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
current_memberships = current_user.memberships
user_names = User.where('users.id in ?', current_memberships.pluck(:user_id).compact.uniq)
                 .select('users.name')
                 .map(&:name)
member_names = Member.where('members.id in ?', current_memberships.pluck(:member_id).compact.uniq)
                     .select('members.name')
                     .map(&:name)

# concat the array of user names and member names
user_names + member_names
```

Comment: The only trouble of this, the result is an array and not active relation.

Comment: Yes, it will give you an array of names. So, you want active record relation?

Comment: It's not my question, but I have an opinion, that active relation is a better choice :)

Comment: This works @KMRakibulIslam - Here's my solution, using AR:
    User:
      `user_name = User.order(:first_name).where("first_name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").where(id: current_user.memberships.pluck(:invited_id))`
    Member:
      `member_name = Member.order(:first_name).where("first_name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").where(id: current_user.memberships.pluck(:member_id))`
Then concatenate
     `user_name + member_name`

Hrmm.. Don't know how to fomat this correctly sorry.

Comment: And thanks for the suggestion to chain the `compact` method!